# Add Multiple Unit Test in Single Class File - Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

Hello i want to add multiple test scenarios in a single file. I am using selenium for c#. Need your help how make this happen

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show us a [mcve] of your existing single test scenario.

Comment: Why cant you just use multiple methods and annotate them with [TestMethod] ? What you want is possible,not sure where your issue is.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Microsoft testing framework then you need to add the attribute

`[TestClass]` to your class and `[TestMethod]` to each method that encapsulates a test.

Note that your class must be marked as public and the test methods must also be public and void.

You can see a more detailed guide on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx#BKMK_Create_the_test_class)

Comment: Yes you are right but the problem is i am using selenium and in selenum first thing you do is open the browser. How can i open the browser at every test ?

Comment: @JohnyAli Agree with mjwills here - you need to post an example, the question you asked isn't the one you need the answer to